# Accessing Scipy ode solver's internal steps

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I'm currently making the switch from MATLAB to Python for a project that involves solving differential equations.

In MATLAB if the t array that's passed only contains two elements, the solver outputs all the intermediate steps of the simulation. However, in Python you just get the start and end point. To get time points in between you have to explicitly specify the time points you want.

```
from scipy import integrate as sp_int
import numpy as np

def odeFun(t,y):
    k = np.ones((2))
    dy_dt = np.zeros(y.shape)
    dy_dt[0]= k[1]*y[1]-k[0]*y[0]
    dy_dt[1]=-dy_dt[0]
    return(dy_dt)

t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
yOut = sp_int.odeint(odeFun,[1,0],t)
```

I've also looked into the following method:

```
solver = sp_int.ode(odefun).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
solver.set_initial_value([1,0],0)
dt = 0.01
solver.integrate(solver.t+dt)
```

However, it still requires an explicit `dt`. From reading around I understand that Python's solvers (e.g. `'vode'`) calculates intermediate steps for the `dt` requested, and then interpolates that time point and outputs it. What I'd like though is to get all these intermediate steps directly without the interpolation. This is because they represent the minimum number of points required to fully describe the time series within the integration tolerances.

Is there an option available to do that?

I'm working in Python 3.

Comment: *"and then interpolates that time point and outputs it"* Are you sure of that? Sounds a bit unusual to me. The normal procedure would be to shorten the first step that would overshoot, so it hits the requested point. -- Re getting your hands on the timesteps. If you are really desperate you can always instrument the integrand function and log the *t* with which it was called.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Interpolating is quite usual for some methods where the interpolation can be assumed to be sufficiently accurate and shortening time steps would be comparably tedious. `scipy.integrate.odeint` interpolates, as can be seen from the `tcur` data (see my answer) as well as from the logging you suggest – neither contains the initial time steps.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: *If you are really desperate you can always instrument the integrand function and log the t with which it was called.* – That would not give you the desired result as many solvers also need to evaluate the derivative (`odeFun`) at times between the steps, e.g., the [explicit midpoint method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method) to give a simple example.

Comment: *This is because they represent the minimum number of points required to fully describe the time series within the integration tolerances.* – Can you elaborate why you need this information? I am sensing an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Wow, that's a lot of wrong statements in a single comment even by my standards. Thanks for setting them right.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the reason I would like that is because my problem is stiff and the sysstem can change quickly and slowly. But, I don't know in advance when these quick and slow changes occur. I don't want to arbitrarily choose a set of time points to sample because I might choose a step size that's too big and miss some interesting features, or needlessly small and use excessive memory. I believe the variable step size used by the solver ensures that all features of the time series is captured but since it only uses the biggest step size, will minimise the output size as well.

Comment: @sleepyzelaot: Good to know. I made a small edit to my answer in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `scipy.integrate.odeint`

`odeint` has an option `full_output` that allows you to obtain a dictionary with information on the integration, including `tcur` which is:

> vector with the value of t reached for each time step. (will always be at least as large as the input times).

(Note the second sentence: The actual steps are always as fine as your desired output. If you want use the minimum number of necessary step, you must ask for a coarse sampling.)

Now, this does not give you the values, but we can obtain those by integrating a second time using these very steps:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def f(y,t):
    return np.array([y[1]-y[0],y[0]-y[1]])

start,end = 0,10 # time range we want to integrate
y0 = [1,0]       # initial conditions

# Function to add the initial time and the target time if needed:
def ensure_start_and_end(times):
    times = np.insert(times,0,start)
    if times[-1] < end:
        times = np.append(times,end)
    return times

# First run to establish the steps
first_times = np.linspace(start,end,100)
first_run   = odeint(f,y0,first_times,full_output=True)
first_steps = np.unique(first_run[1]["tcur"])

# Second run to obtain the results at the steps
second_times = ensure_start_and_end(first_steps)
second_run   = odeint(f,y0,second_times,full_output=True,h0=second_times[0])
second_steps = np.unique(second_run[1]["tcur"])

# ensuring that the second run actually uses (almost) the same steps.
np.testing.assert_allclose(first_steps,second_steps,rtol=1e-5)

# Your desired output
actual_steps = np.vstack((second_times, second_run[0].T)).T
```

## `scipy.integrate.ode`

Having some experience with this module, I am not aware of any way to obtain the step size without digging deeply into the internals.