# How to know the middle trajectory of ode solver in python

Tags: python, math, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I am using Python package to solve ODE equation. However, I need to know the middle state or in other words the trajectory of ode solver in python.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
   solution = odeint(fun,initial_values,tspan)
```

Here the output just gives me me the final state, not the middle steps, How can I get the middle steps?

Thanks

I have tried this

```
   solution = odeint(fun,initial_values,tspan)
```

The output gives me the initial values and the final output. How can I know the steps between the initial values and the final output?

[[ 0.5 -0.5]
[5 5]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Scipy ode solver's internal steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433122/accessing-scipy-ode-solvers-internal-steps)

Comment: Use solve_ivp, `method="LSODA"` is somewhat equivalent to odeint. Note that there the t_span argument is just the endpoints of the integration interval, t_eval defines the customized output. If not given, you get the internal nodes. Use atol, rtol to increase the density of internal steps.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please realise that you're talking out of context. Please include any relevant `import` in your question, so the people who read your question can know where this function `odeint` comes from. I assume it's [`from scipy.integrate import odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), but I'm wildly guessing here. We don't like to guess; please be explicit. Also, if it's scipy, please add tag `[scipy]` on your question. With this tag, people who are knowledgeable about scipy will find your question more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) is the set of time values at which you want the solution to be returned.  In your case, put the desired times in your `tspan` argument. E.g. `tspan = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)` will get you the solution at t=0.0, 0.01, 0.02, ..., 0.99, 1.0.  Take another look at the example in the docstring, where it shows the plot of a solution that was generated with `t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)`.